# Set permissions of the installation directory

Tags: cmake

I would like to change the permissions on the install directory (specified in CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX), but I don't find how to do that.

I'm able to set the permission of all the installed files, but not for the automatically generated directories.

For example, if my CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is /softs/myappli/64/gcc/4.7.2 I would like to be able to set the permission of /softs/myappli to "700" when I do my "make install".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to do so, you may use `install` command w/ the following signature:

```
install([[SCRIPT <file>] [CODE <code>]] [...])`
```

and write a code to change permissions at install time. I.e. smth like this:

```
execute_process(COMMAND /bin/chmod ARGS 0700 "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
```

put this to a `chmod.cmake` or to a string and then call `install` above.

Comment: It seems a good solution. The only problem is there is no rules on the order of calling install commands. So I created a sub-directory "post-install" at the end of my main CMakeLists.txt to call this install command.

Comment: install(CODE ...) is an alternative solution for those, who don't want to add another `.cmake` file

Comment: The argument `ARGS` in the [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/execute_process.html) call seems to be superfluous. My instance started working after I removed it.